# Increase the height of residual plots in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which outputs diagnostics from a regression. Is there any way for me to increase the height of these plots to take up more space on the page?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("diagnostics")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 output$diagnostics <- renderPlot({
   par(mfrow = c(2,2))
   plot(lm(hp ~ ., data = mtcars))
 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: From [`?plotOutput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/plotOutput.html), one can set `height='800px'` or similar.

Comment: that did it. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave a "height" argument to renderPlot() before the list of output arguments

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    plotOutput("diagnostics")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$diagnostics <- renderPlot(
        height = 500,
        {
        par(mfrow = c(2,2))
        plot(lm(hp ~ ., data = mtcars))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```